# How to use nocontent flag with ft.search to retrieve only keys

Tags: redis, node-redis

I have a requirement to search through redis cache using full text search but the response I get has key and value which is a lot of data.  I just need key string to clean up those cache entries later.

```
client.ft.search(index, searchString,{ LIMIT: { from: 0, size: 0 }});
```

Is there a way to pass nocontent flag in the above query similar to redis FT.SEARCH?

```
FT.SEARCH "idx:index" "@response:*search_text*" LIMIT 0 0 nocontent
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in node-redis API to fetch keys without any values

```
client.ft.searchNoContent(index, searchString,{ LIMIT: { from: 0, size: 0 }});
```

Please refer documentation [here](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/packages/search/lib/commands/SEARCH_NOCONTENT.ts)